# Distribution of KECCAK-256 hash values

Tags: blockchain, hash, keccak, statistics

Are values hashed using `KECCAK - 256` uniformly distributed? If I use a `KECCAK - 256` hash and then convert it to a number in a range `0 - N` using the modulo operation, would the probability of obtaining any of the numbers in this range be equal to 1/N, or would there be a deviation from the ideal distribution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I came across [this paper](http://www.ijcee.org/papers/439-JE503.pdf) that looks at using Keccak-256 (the original one that Ethereum uses, not SHA3) as a PRNG. It subjects the output of the hash to a large number of tests of randomness and it passes them all.

Conclusion:

> The experimental results show the KECCAK hash function has excellent
>   pseudo randomness, and its security shows that it can be utilized to
>   generate pseudorandom bit sequences.

According to the test results, the sequence of bits generated by applying Keccak-256 to successive integers is indistinguishable from random, and thus your modulo approach ought to be fine - i.e. uniformly distributed.