# are all bits of a keccak256 'uniformly distributed'?

Tags: hash, randomness, keccak

If I have a truly random data source, and generate keccak256 hashes of the numbers of this source:

N1 = keccak256(rnd1)
N2 = keccak256(rnd2)
N3 = keccak256(rnd3)
...

are all 256 bits of the resulting hashes uniformly distributed, or are there specific bits for which a 1 is more/less likely than a 0 for example, or which stand in some predictable correclation to specific other bits?

Comment: Hi, maybe you can also consider to post/move this question on this stack exchange https://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I have to admit, I'm not sure how to move a question to another stack exchange - do I just double-post?

Comment: Maybe this answer may help. But we will need some user with more than 3k reputation 

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85017/how-do-i-move-my-own-question-to-another-stack-exchange-site. Ok I flagged the question maybe some admin can help you ^^

Comment: Possible duplicate of 
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/30858/distribution-of-keccak-256-hash-values