# How come these 2 Ethereum addresses are identical except for 1 character?

Tags: addresses, keccak

I always assumed that Ethereum addresses were, more or less, uniformly (randomly) distributed over their 40-char hex representation.

Is that not the case?

I've found these 2 addresses that only differ in their first character.

```
0x0520cb868B5bb977F51C8Ad85A4D38f904A09007
0x9520cB868B5BB977F51c8aD85a4D38F904a09007
```

The chances of this happening (birthday paradox) are so small, it's next to impossible if distribution is indeed somewhat uniform.

A simpler calc (or at least one that I how to calculate [here](https://kevingal.com/apps/collision.html)) is too check the chances of, say, the 20-char suffix (= 16^20 = 2^80 or 80 bits of info) of 2 items colliding in the supposed uniform distribution. Chances of 1 collision with 200M items (about the number of ethereum addresses which have activity on Etheruem mainnet) is `~1.6543e-8`

Only conclusion must be that distribution is not near uniform.

Now a public ethereum address is generated in a couple of stages (steps from [here](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/accounts/#:%7E:text=Account%20creation&text=The%20public%20key%20is%20generated,adding%200x%20to%20the%20beginning.) :

1. given a 64-char hex private key (256 bits of info)
2. generate public key from private key using [Elliptic Curve Signature algo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm)
3. taking the last 20 bytes of the Keccak-256 hash of the public key and adding 0x to the beginning

Now, I've found [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/30858/distribution-of-keccak-256-hash-values) article suggesting that step 3 (taking the Keccak-256 hash) results in a good randomly uniform distribution.

So, only step 1. or step 2. limit randomness here.
Anyone?

Comment: You got these two addresses generated by yourself,  or you just found them online?

Comment: Found them online

Comment: Online, in some register of addresses?

Comment: As part of indexing all Ethereum transactions, I encountered this collision, based on my assumption that I could encode ethereum addresses with less entropy than their original 160 bits. Turns out I am wrong. I'm pretty sure this is not a unique case, but this one tripped all the wires.

Comment: Yeah, I think more realistic explanation is that somene made a typo, there are likely a numbers of such addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This hasn't happened. I'm almost sure for the https://etherscan.io/address/0x0520cb868B5bb977F51C8Ad85A4D38f904A09007 nobody has the private key. There is only one incoming transaction, and I think they wanted to send funds to that another one `0x9520cb868B5bb977F51C8Ad85A4D38f904A09007` address but missed the first `9` (`0` was prepended automatically). *There is an ERC20 token at the address, but it was just airdropped in a batch.*

Comment: Ah that could be the reason. You assume no access to private key based on no transfers out at all?

Comment: Right. 1 No transfers out. 2. Both addresses were "active" (that one with `0x05..` just received) at the same **Date** - 1809 days ago. 3. As you have already noticed the chances to generate two addresses with levenshtein distance of 1 at a similar point in time is not realistic.

Answer (score 0):

ETH address has **160bits** == **20Bytes** == **40 charahters**

So the odds of full address collision are `2^160`

The chances for your case (collision in all but one character) are `2^156`

A big number to be sure, but still "somewhat" plausible. But also a hell of a suspicious, if I am being honest.

Comment: Yeah. If was talking about the chance of any of the 200M addresses colliding, a change that the linked collision calculator cannot even approximate, so I did it with the half the length (=80 bits)